# Correct way to setup a web development environment with zend studio and git?

Tags: git, github, mamp, bitbucket, zend-studio

I wanted to know if any one can tell me what should be the procedure to setup a web development environment
with zend studio , git and bitbucket as my provate repository

i have mamp,zend studio installed on my mac, i  installed github app created an account on bitbucket

my mamp htdocs url is /user/rajneesh/htdocs in this i create project folder example1,example2

i want to work on my local machine with git and web development and testing is done on local i want everything get uploaded  (i dont know from my bitbucket repository or from my local machine project specific folder) to my live server where i use to host every project in a subdomain like project1.example.com , project2.example.com

I was wondering if any one can tell me what should be the correct way to do this so i dont need to manually upload entire project or slight changes i made in my local machine to my live server

I would be glad if someone can tell me step by step guide

Answer (score 0):

you could clone the repository from the live server; maybe create a separate production branch and use that. be sure to not deliver the .git folder in apache (or whatever server you use).